# Popup/Overlay screen in android honeycomb

Tags: android, google-maps, popup, overlay, android-3.0-honeycomb

I would like to achieve a popup/overlay screen like Places (i`m more interested how can i place that screen for example in the right/left side of the screen ) in the android maps application (image below). I can create an activity and use the Dialog theme, this mostly resolve my problem, but it placed center in the screen. Somebody have any better idea how i can create a popup/overlay screen like the places in a non-map application and place to top/right of the screen ?. My guess they did it with map overlays.

[image: Places in map]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, here's what I did... I used a FrameLayout to overlay a LinearLayout where I can fill it with a View. Here's an excerpt of my code:

XML:

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1">

     <fragment class="com.some.location.to.fragment"
          android:id="@+id/fragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

     <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/overlay_pane"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:visibility="gone"
          android:background="@color/transparent">

      </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Then in my code on some button, I would just add a View (in your case it can just be the dialog's contents) to the overlay_pane LinearLayout.

Java example:

```
ViewGroup container = findViewById(R.id.overlay_pane);
container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
container.addView(some_view_you_inflated);
```

But this inflated view would have the following background: **@drawable/dialog_full_holo_light** for a nice border effect like the Honeycomb style.

You can find the background drawable in your SDK in the following folder

> your_SDK_dir/platforms/android-12/data/res/drawable-hdpi/dialog_full_holo_light.9.png

So just copy that into your drawables.

Note: that you can also use the dialog_full_holo_dark or any custom background for the same effect.

I hope that helps :) Let me know if I was unclear at any point

*Note*: Instead of using a fragment, you could merely use a LinearLayout with match_parent for both layout_width and layout_height. And then you would fill that LinearLayout with the "background" UI (in the question's example.. that would be the map)

Comment: one more thing.. you can control where the overlay will appear by using the android:layout_gravity property on the view you inflate

Comment: Thanks for the idea (i`ve tried to did from an other point of view), i will try it when i have a little time for that. I will need to put the overlay over a tabhost, but hopefully will not screw up anything.

Comment: What does the fragment in your XML do? I'm a bit new to fragments and I'm confused since you didn't post the Java for com.some.location.to.fragment

Comment: There is no addView() method on a View object, so your third line in the second block of code isn't possible

Comment: The fragment content doesn't matter. Instead of using a fragment you could just use a LinearLayout filled with the UI. See the update to my answer. Also, I fixed the bug with the View object. Sorry, it should have been a ViewGroup.

Comment: The reason why I used fragment in the example is because the Honeycomb UI seems to promote the use of fragments (I'm guessing because of its usefulness when designing an app for both phones and tablets). But as I mentioned a regular LinearLayout with content is fine.