# How to make a maps like overlay in Honeycomb

Tags: android, popup, overlay, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

Basically, this question [Popup/Overlay screen in android honeycomb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288811/popup-overlay-screen-in-android-honeycomb)

but the answer provided doesn't explain what to do with the fragment inside the FrameLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fragment` in the XML is the underlying activity.  In the case of that question, it would be the `fragment` that is running the map.

Please be more specific with your question to help people who use the search feature and Google.